# can I speficy different id types in different id spaces when using neo4j-admin import

Tags: neo4j

I'm new to neo4j, and Im trying to use its import tool to import data to a new database. 
My question is:
can I specify different id types in different id spaces?

For example:
I hace nodes "user" and "address", each has an ID space (user-id) and (address-id). I want IDs in (user-id) be integer while those in (address-id) string. What should I do?

I tried adding ":int" in the csv header like this:

uid:ID(User-ID):int

but it turns to be wrong. And I know neo4j-admin import has options 
--id-type=, but it's for all the IDs. Is there any way to specify different ID types in different id spaces? or it is not supported in neo4j?

Comment: Can you share what the data you are trying to import looks like? Why can't you import it as multiple CSVs? And depending on what your source is, why didn't you use admin dump+load?